# Does specifying -type option improve find performance in linux?

Tags: linux, performance, search, find

As you know there is an option for `find` command which allows you to tell if you're looking for a 'file' or 'directory'. I was wondering if specifying that would improve find performance (speed)?
like:

`find / -type file -name foo.bar`

is faster than

`find / -name foo.bar`

or it does not make any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in some cases it does improve performance.

By default `find` applies logical AND to its tests but **the latter test is not evaluated if the former is false**. So if you add a super fast test which almost always fails at the very beginning then it can save many executions of following (say: slow) tests and in this case this additional test *does* improve performance.

Go to directory with many files and few symlinks. Compare

```
time find -exec test -L {} \; -print
```

to

```
time find -type l -exec test -L {} \; -print
```

This is artificial yet enlightening example. The two tests (`-type l` and `-exec test -L {} \;`) do the same job, the two `find` commands yield the same results. However `-exec` creates additional process and this is relatively slow. In my home directory the first command takes two minutes; the second command takes six seconds.

Comment: (1) Good point.  I (obviously) didn’t consider the case of `-type` being *followed by* slower tests (since the question didn’t suggest that that was going to happen, but I should have thought of it anyway).  (2) What is this `type` *program* that you’re running?  I get `find: ‘type’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @G-Man Oops. I meant `test`; in my console I run `test`. Mindless mistake here. Should be OK now.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't know about the internal mechanism. honestly, I hoped it uses file table or other file system meta-data to speed up the search process but looks like it just traverse the directory structure as Jim Dennis mentioned [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-find-command-work).

Comment: @AliQanavatian What is your point? All I'm saying is: if the first test fails then the rest is not evaluated at all; so you can speed things up sometimes thanks to additional test, even if it doesn't change the final output.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your commands won’t even work, for two reasons:

   - The starting directory (or directories), if any,
     must always appear before the test(s), if any,
     so your commands would have to be

     ```
     find / -name foo.bar …
     ```
   - Generally you can’t say `-type file`; it should be `-type f`.
2. Why would you even suspect that adding an additional test
   would improve performance?
3. Theoretically, it could *decrease* performance, because you’re doing

   ```
   if (filename = "foo.bar"  AND  filetype = "f")
       print filename
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   if (filename = "foo.bar")
       print filename
   ```

   i.e., you’re giving it more work to do. 
   In reality, though, the difference will be negligible. 
   `find` already has to get the filetype information
   to see which entries are directories
   (and therefore need to be searched recursively). 
   Once it has that information,
   checking whether it is a plain file requires just a few CPU instructions,
   and is very fast.

Comment: The only case I can think of is a `-exec` test that involves an external process (and this process just fails silently if passed the wrong type anyway).

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re saying. Are you saying the same thing [Kamil Maciorowski is saying](https://superuser.com/q/1252217/354511#1252248)?

Comment: Yes, that's the same ting.

Comment: You can omit the starting directory, at least in GNU find. Man page says *If no starting-point is specified, `.' is assumed.*